# Destructuring mapStateToProps in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently learning desctructuring in JS and want to know if there's a better way to write this function:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.data.token,
    anonUsername: state.data.anonUsername,
    showAuthModal: state.data.showAuthModal,
    client_id: state.data.client_id,
    client_secret: state.data.client_secret,
    env: state.data.env,
    username: state.data.username,
    invitationAuth: state.data.invitationAuth,
    inviteLink: state.data.inviteLink,
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `state.data` look like (does it have more keys than just the ones shown here, if so, how many more)?

Comment: proabably an object

Comment: if that's all your state has, then I'd just do `mapStateToProps = state => { ...state.data } `

Comment: @NickParsons no, keys in state.data are the same

Comment: @L_Fr in that case, `state.data` is the object you want to return from your function (like people in the answers have pointed out)

Comment: @L_Fr so all you want to do is a 1:1 flat copy of `state.data`, right? then go with `mapStateToProps  = state => ({ ...state.data })`

Comment: @NickParsons we'd need to know more about the code that uses `mapStateToProps` to tell wether it's safe to return `satae.data`. #mutation

Comment: @Thomas : for the sake of safety, always return a shallow copy of the object

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I was looking [here](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#only-return-new-object-references-if-needed) which seems to suggest that most of the time you'll want to keep it as a reference to prevent unneeded re-renders.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your state contains more than those keys, I'd do something like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { token, anonUsername, slowAuthModal, client_id, client_secret, env, username, invitationAuth, inviteLink } = state.data;
  return {
    token,
    anonUsername,
    showAuthModal,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    env,
    username,
    invitationAuth,
    inviteLink,
  }
}
```

If your state has only those keys, then I'd do something like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state.data });
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple options I can identify:

Just return `state.data`. I might be mis-reading, but it looks like all the prop names are the same.

If you don’t want to pass that specific reference around, make a shallow copy with the spread operator: `{ ...state.data }`.

With either of these, if you’re using something like typescript, you can prevent folks from trying to access props you don’t intend to expose.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try this by destructuring the state.data object, it makes your file clearer :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { token, anonUsername, slowAuthModal, client_id, client_secret, env, username, invitationAuth, inviteLink } = state.data;
  return {
    token,
    anonUsername,
    showAuthModal,
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    env,
    username,
    invitationAuth,
    inviteLink,
  }
}
```